# Enabling SSL in Tomcat with a private CA

Tags: tomcat, ssl

We are setting up a web server with Tomcat and our tech services have given me with .csr, .key and two .cer files generated using our internal PKI. One .cer file is for the new site and the other saying "can be added to the trusted root store on other machines that we need to test from"...

I added the .cer for the site in to the keystore using Java keytool. Configured the server.xml  pointing it to the new keystore. Thats all I did. But when I try to access the site I am getting "Error 113 (net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH)" error.

I have enabled the SSL for tomcat with self sign certificates but this is not familiar for me. Do I have to import the key file as well. What should I do with the root certificate. I have to enabled client authentication.

Command I used to import cer file

*keytool -import -trusrcacerts -alias myalias -file /wip/myalias.cer -keystore /opt/ks.jks*

keytool -list command list the certificate.

Server.xml has following entry,

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
           keystoreFile="/opt/tomcat/keystore/keystore.jks" keystorePass="passPhrase" />
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: After some more googling found the issue. I think there were few issues (just a guess). The main is the key has not imported into the keystore. When I tried to import it got an "Unable to load certificate error".... bit more testing revealed that I has the cer in DER format. Had to convert into PEM format using **openssl x509 -in myalias.cer -inform der -outform pem -out myalias.pem** command and then convert that and key into single PKCS12 format using **openssl pkcs12 -export -in myalias.pem -inkey myalias.key > mykeystore.p12**

Comment: hen import the PKCS12 file into a keystore using the command: **keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore mykeystore.p12 -destkeystore finalstore.jks -srcstoretype pkcs12**. Using that in the server.xml solves the problem.